# Bukkit Configuration File Creation Error

Tags: java, configuration-files, bukkit

I'm kind of new to programming bukkit plugins so please go easy on my if the answer is obvious. I am trying to create a second configuration file to store locations and other data, but when I run my plugin I keep getting a `NullPointerException`.

Here is my code:

```
package blah.blah.blah.XD;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class KingdomLocationsFile extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    public Kingdoms plugin;

    public KingdomLocationsFile(Kingdoms plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    private File KingdomLocationsFile;
    private FileConfiguration KingdomLocations;

    public void reloadKingdomLocations() {
        if (KingdomLocationsFile == null) {
            KingdomLocationsFile = new File(getDataFolder(), "KingdomLocations.yml");
        }
        KingdomLocations = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(KingdomLocationsFile);

        // Look for defaults in the jar
        InputStream defConfigStream = plugin.getResource("KingdomLocations.yml");
        if (defConfigStream != null) {
            YamlConfiguration defConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(defConfig
                Stream);
            KingdomLocations.setDefaults(defConfig);
        }
    }

    public FileConfiguration getKingdomLocations() {
        if (KingdomLocations == null) {
            this.reloadKingdomLocations();
        }
        return KingdomLocations;
    }

    public void saveKingdomLocations() {
        if (KingdomLocations == null || KingdomLocationsFile == null) {
        return;
        }
        try {
            getKingdomLocations().save(KingdomLocationsFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            this.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not save config to " + KingdomLoc
                ationsFile, ex);
        }
    }

    public boolean force = false;

    public List<Location> getLocationsList(final String path) {
        final List<Location> List = new ArrayList<Location>();
        if (this.KingdomLocations.contains(path) && this.KingdomLocations.isConfigu
                rationSection(path)) {
            final Set<String> keys = this.KingdomLocations.getConfigurationSect
                        ion(path).getKeys(false);
            if (keys.size() > 0) {
                final Location[] key = (Location[]) keys.toArray();
                for (final Location element : key) {
                    List.add(this.getKingdomLocation(path +"." +(Locati
                                        on) element));
                }
            }
        }
        return List;
    }

    private Location getKingdomLocation(String path) {
        Location loc = (Location) this.KingdomLocations.get(path);
        return loc;
    }
}
```

...And here is the error:

```
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Plugin Test Server>java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukk
it-1.5.1-R0.1-20130326.111705-23.jar -o true
229 recipes
27 achievements
16:06:39 [INFO] Starting minecraft server version 1.5.1
16:06:39 [INFO] Loading properties
16:06:39 [INFO] Default game type: SURVIVAL
16:06:39 [INFO] Generating keypair
16:06:39 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
16:06:39 [INFO] This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.4.7-R1.0
-75-g7f25632-b2717jnks (MC: 1.5.1) (Implementing API version 1.5.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT
)
16:06:39 [INFO] [Kingdoms] Loading Kingdoms v1.0
16:06:39 [INFO] Preparing level "world"
16:06:39 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: 3764664766498884770)
16:06:40 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed: 3764664766498884770)
16:06:40 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 20%
16:06:41 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 2 (Seed: 3764664766498884770)
16:06:41 [INFO] [Kingdoms] Enabling Kingdoms v1.0
16:06:41 [SEVERE] Error occurred while enabling Kingdoms v1.0 (Is it up to date?
)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.treeclimber17.kingdoms.KingdomLocationsFile.reloadKingdomLocation
s(KingdomLocationsFile.java:35)
    at com.treeclimber17.kingdoms.KingdomLocationsFile.getKingdomLocations(K
ingdomLocationsFile.java:44)
    at com.treeclimber17.kingdoms.Kingdoms.onEnable(Kingdoms.java:14) [THIS PROBABLY         DOESN't MATTER...]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader
.java:457)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManage
r.java:381)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.jav
a:282)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.
java:264)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.j(MinecraftServer.java:3
01)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.e(MinecraftServer.java:2
80)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:2
40)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.jav
a:150)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java
:379)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:5
73)
16:06:41 [INFO] Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
16:06:41 [INFO] Done (1.885s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
```

Comment: Also, try reading http://linuxsilo.net/docs/smart-questions_en.html

Answer (score 0):

You should keep bukkit-related questions on bukkit's own support page (since it's an API), found here: http://forums.bukkit.org/forums/plugin-development.5/

That being said, try using try-catch to see if the statement is still null here:

```
KingdomLocations = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(KingdomLocationsFile);
```

Something like:

```
try {
    KingdomLocations = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(KingdomLocationsFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception caught in method");
    System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
}
```

A bit of freehand, but without the api at hand / line numbers, it's hard to pick out exactly what the issue is.